# React App Crashing Due to undefined PropTypes.node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, webpack, react-proptypes

I ran into an issue today while working on the node.js + react based project was created with react v.15.0.0 , it has several deprecated features so I upgraded the project to use react v.16.2.0.

And now it is crashing and it cannot be compiled with webpack no more :(

I have the error message as:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
[3]     at Object.defineProperty.value (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:528:40)
[3]     at __webpack_require__ (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:20:30)
[3]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:406:22)
[3]     at __webpack_require__ (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:20:30)
[3]     at Object.defineProperty.value (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:342:16)
[3]     at __webpack_require__ (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:20:30)
[3]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:185:14)
[3]     at __webpack_require__ (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:20:30)
[3]     at Object.defineProperty.value (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:56:16)
[3]     at __webpack_require__ (/Volumes/Develop/MyPortfolio/edward/dist/server.js:20:30)
[3] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I traced back to /my project/dist/server.js file, this is the line that caused the crashing :

```
ExternalLink.propTypes = {
      children: _react2.default.PropTypes.node
    };
```

And _react2 is declared as :

```
var _react = __webpack_require__(3);

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
```

I have did some research and found that React 16.x has a separate package for the type check 'Prop-Types',  I actually tried swap the old function with the new one like this:

```
   var _propType = require("prop-types");

    ExternalLink.propTypes = {
      children: _propType.default.PropTypes.node
    };
```

Still no luck, I am out of idea at this moment, would appreciate if someone can offer suggestions or workaround on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just use `_propTypes.node` instead of `_propType.default.PropTypes.node`

```
var _propType = require("prop-types");

ExternalLink.propTypes = {
 children: _propType.node
};
```

Since React 16, PropTypes was split out into its own package and the default export of that package is the PropTypes object so you just use it directly vs look up `.default.PropTypes.`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var _propType = require("prop-types");

ExternalLink.propTypes = {
  children: _propType.node
};
```

I'm using create-react-app and swapping the ES6 module import with this CommonJS syntax works fine